# Programmatically remove attribute from attribute-set from models

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I’ve tried removing an eav_entity_attribute using this code:

```
$entAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$set->getId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_id',$attId)->getFirstItem();
$entAttr->delete();
```

but it doesn’t work. I receive this error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ‘attribute_set_id’ in ‘where clause’’

How can I delete an eav_entity_attribute this way?

Answer (score 2):

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','attribute_name')->delete();
```

or to delete it directly from the attribute set:

```
$setup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup); 
$setup->startSetup(); 
$setup->deleteTableRow('eav/entity_attribute',
'attribute_id',$setup->getAttributeId('catalog_product','attribute_code_here'),'attribute_set_id',$setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'Default') 
);
$setup->endSetup();
```

Comment: Won't this delete the attribute itself, and not the attribute from the attribute-set?

Comment: My code isn't is a setup script, will the code above still work

Comment: why not its just php?